# Vlad the deployer on Dreamhost - initial script

Tags: svn, deployment, rake, automated-deploy, vlad-deployer

I'm trying to deploy an app with SVN and Vlad the deployer.
Vlad and its dependencies are installed and seem OK.

I'm trying the following:

```
rake prod vlad:update
```

Being my config/deploy.rb file:

```
task :prod do
set :application, "xxx"
set :deploy_timestamped, "false"
set :user,       "username"
set :scm_user,   "scmusername"
set :repository, "http://domain.com/svn/app"
set :domain,     "domain.com"
set :deploy_to,  "/home/username/deployments/app"
puts "Production deployment to #{deploy_to}"
end
```

I have done "rake prod vlad:setup" already, that's fine.
But when calling "rake prod vlad:update", I get the following

```
A    ...file
Exported revision 14.
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/username/deployments/drupalgestalt/releases/20100503164225/public/system' to     `/home/username/deployments/drupalgestalt/shared/system': No such file or directory
rake aborted!
execution failed with status 1: ssh domain.com ln -s 
/home/username/deployments/app/shared/log 
/home/username/deployments/app/releases/20100503164225/log && ln -s 
/home/username/deployments/app/shared/system 
/home/username/deployments/app/releases/20100503164225/public/system && ln -s     
/home/username/deployments/app/shared/pids 
/home/username/deployments/app/releases/20100503164225/tmp/pids
```

Apparently it complains when creating the ln, but permissions are all set up fine.

Am I doing anything wrong? I'm just starting with Vlad on the assumption it was super-easy to set up. Had played a bit with cap in the past, and I do like Vlad idea.

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOL for "Vlad the Deployer" :) :) :) Who came up with that name? From the Logo I assume they are well aware of [where the name comes from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlad_III_the_Impaler) :P

Comment: Yeah, there's a logo you don't see every day.

Comment: And after some reading on Vlad the Impaler one becomes really, really glad to live in the 21st century. Brrrrr.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a path error.  Try changing your :deploy_to line to the correct path.  I'm fairly certain that "/home/username/" is not it.

Answer (score 0):

more specifically... it looks like you're missing the "shared" directory that its trying to symlink to. Do you have the following directory set up?

```
/home/username/deployments/drupalgestalt/shared/system
```

And yes, "username" is a problem too. You'll need to update the following line:

```
set :deploy_to,  "/home/username/deployments/app"
```

to

```
set :deploy_to,  "/home/#{username}/deployments/#{application}"
```

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for the reply.
I actually solved by using the namespace vlad to define the tasks. It looked like it wasn't taken. In theory shouldn't matter though.
I created those common directories that Vlad requests - but nothing worked out until I changed the conf to sth like:

namespace :vlad do
  ...
  desc "Full deployment cycle"
  remote_task :deploy => [ :update, :start_app ]  
  ...
end

That is defining the task deploy into the namespace vlad - that was needed, and define it as a remote_task.


PS: I changed my username by "username", just not to disclose too much info. That is fine.

Comment: Ah cool - yeah, that makes sense. I wasn't sure if it was purposeful or a copy-paste error... :)

namespaces huh? I'll have to think about that as I'm having some issues with cap-deploying on dreamhost. Might be worth a try...